# How to filter and remove the noise of image get from predicted image

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation, imagefilter

I did image segmentation using U-net, and after trained the model could get the predicted image of one test data.

```
a = X_test[n]
b = y_test[n]
input = np.expand_dims(a,axis=0)
mask = np.expand_dims(b,axis=0)
preds_test = unet_model.predict(input)

y_true = mask
y_pred = tf.cast(preds_test, tf.double)
dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
unet_model.evaluate(input, mask)
```

By using preds_test, I could get the predicted image.
However I found there is noise on this image, so I need to remove these noise from this image, and I want to get the dice score of this image.
What I want to get in final is value of `dice_coef(y_true, y_filter)`. The problem is I don't have any idea to get the value of 'y_filter'.

How can I solve this problem?
It maybe hard to understand but I have no idea to solve this problem..

Comment: Use `tf.image.psnr` which returns the Peak Signal-to-Noise Ratio between image1 and image2. `psnr= tf.image.psnr(im1, im2, max_val=1.0)`. For more information on the library visit https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/psnr